# by using truffle & metamask deployed my contracts, but a error occurred when sending a transaction on web

Tags: truffle, metamask

[image]

**This is the err information.**

[image]

**This is the web I built.**

Now the problem you see is that when I click the vote button, pay
the gas, and send a transaction, but than error occurred.

I write my program based on the Truffle's [Pet Shop tutorial](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/pet-shop).

Here is my contract code (`Adoption.sol`):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Adoption {

  mapping (bytes32 => uint8) public votesReceived;
  bytes32[] public candidateList;

  function Voting(bytes32[] candidateNames) public {
    candidateList = candidateNames;
  }

  function totalVotesFor(bytes32 candidate) view public returns (uint8) {
    require(validCandidate(candidate));
    return votesReceived[candidate];
  }

  function voteForCandidate(bytes32 candidate) public {
    require(validCandidate(candidate));
    votesReceived[candidate]  += 1;
  }

  function validCandidate(bytes32 candidate) view public returns (bool) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < candidateList.length; i++) {
      if (candidateList[i] == candidate) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
   }
}
```

this is my `app.js`:re

```
App = {
    web3Provider: null,
    contracts: {},
    initWeb3: function() {
        // Is there an injected web3 instance?
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            App.web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
        } else {
            // If no injected web3 instance is detected, fall back to Ganache
            App.web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:7545');
        }
        web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
        return App.initContract();
    },

    initContract: function() {
        $.getJSON('Adoption.json', function(data) {
            var AdoptionArtifact = data;
            App.contracts.Adoption = TruffleContract(AdoptionArtifact);
            App.contracts.Adoption.setProvider(App.web3Provider);
            return App.markAdopted();
        });
        return App.bindEvents();
    },

    bindEvents: function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.btn-adopt', App.handleAdopt);
    },
    markAdopted: function() {
        let candidates = {
            "Rama": "candidate-1",
            "Nick": "candidate-2",
            "Jose": "candidate-3"
        };
        var adoptionInstance;
        var candidateNames = Object.keys(candidates);
        for (var i = 0; i < candidateNames.length; i++) {
            var name = candidateNames[i];
            App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                adoptionInstance = instance;
                return adoptionInstance.totalVotesFor.call(name);
            }).then(function(v) {
                var number = v;
                var na = candidates[name];
                document.getElementById(na).innerHTML = number;
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            });
        }
    },


    handleAdopt: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var adoptionInstance;
        let candidates = {
            "Rama": "candidate-1",
            "Nick": "candidate-2",
            "Jose": "candidate-3"
        }
        var candidateName = $("#candidate").val();
        var candidateNames = Object.keys(candidates);
        var content = document.getElementById("candidate").value;
        $("#msg").html("Vote has been submitted. The vote count will increment as soon as the vote is recorded on the blockchain. Please wait.");
        $("#candidate").val("");
        web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            var account = accounts[0];
            App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
                adoptionInstance = instance;
                return adoptionInstance.voteForCandidate(candidateName, {
                    from: account
                });
            }).than(function(result) {
                return App.markAdopted()
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err.message)
            });
        });
    }

};

$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        App.initWeb3();
    });
});
```

Comment: post you contract code in a way that can be copied and not as image.

Comment: i put the plain code on comment

Answer (score 0):

I can't read your code due to the poor formatting, however the tooltip visible in the screenshots seems to indicate two things :

- First, the parameter or value you send into your transaction seems to be 'undefined'. Make sure you call the right spot of data
- The data has to be converted to Hexadecimal, which doesn't seem to be the case.